# How big an asteroid to hold a ship in stable orbit?

Tags: hard-science, orbital-mechanics

A derelict space craft, 1MKg in mass is in a 100km (more or less) orbit above the surface of an asteroid out in the asteroid belt.

How big should the asteroid be to have the ship maintain this orbit for a long period of time (decades).

By stable I mean that the asteroid is large enough to thwart the efforts of the the Sun and Jupiter in the system (the two gorillas in the room) to disrupt the orbit, plus most any small object that happens to be flying by.

Wikipedia suggests "average" asteroid density is $2g/cm^3$, so that's good enough for this exercise. Asteroid is "more sphereish" than not. The barycenter should be deeper within the asteroid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The radius of the [Hill sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere) (the zone in which one body's gravity dominates over another) of a large body on a much smaller satellite (as will be the case for an asteroid and a mere 1 kiloton spacecraft) in a circular orbit is given by

$r_H = a(\frac{m}{3M})^\frac{1}{3}$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis between the asteroid and the body *it* orbits (in this case, the Sun), $m$ is the asteroid's mass, and $M$ is the mass of its parent (the Sun). The main belt starts a little over 2AU away, so as the worst-case scenario, let's set $a = 2 \text{ AU}$, $M = 1M_{sun}$, and then plug in $r_{H} = 100 \text{ km}$, assuming the spacecraft is at the very edge of this stable sphere, and solve for $m$.

We get $m \approx 2.3\times10^{11} \text{ kg}$, which, using your density, requires a spherical asteroid of radius ~**300 m**.

Wikipedia helpfully lets us know that the actual orbital distance to ensure stability is usually closer to half or one-third the Hill radius. In the worst-case one-third threshold, we need to multiply $m$ by 27 to triple the Hill sphere's radius to 300 km, and thus triple the asteroid's radius to **900 m.**

As a quick double-check, the binary asteroid [2006 VW139](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(300163)_2006_VW139) has a semi-major axis between the pair of ~100 km and is made of two asteroids on the order of 1-3 km in diameter, depending on the source (though it is a little further from the Sun). So our estimate seems very roughly right — objects of this size can indeed have satellites in (at least observationally) stable orbits.

Comment: A bit of searching finds 66391 Moshup, about 1.3 km in diameter.  It has a small satellite, Squannit, about 360 m in diameter, orbiting at about 2.6 km: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/66391_Moshup

Comment: Yep, but the OP asked for an orbital radius of about 100 km, so that's the requirement I looked for when finding asteroid binaries. (Admittedly the example I provided is more like orbiting a double-mass asteroid at only 50 km, but it was the closest I could find.)

Comment: The orbital velocity at these parameters is about 6.5 cm/s, which is very tricky to create and maintain. An air or fuel leak, or an escape pod undocking, might quickly accelerate this spacecraft beyond escape velocity.

Comment: @magma Yep 6.5cm/s, and each orbit takes 113 days. And just 2.67cm/s more velocity needed to escape. a 26KJ impulse in the right direction, or a 157KJ impulse in *any* direction, will break the orbit.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I think it would behoove me to put the ship closer to a larger asteroid so that some astronaut landing on it doesn't send both careening out in to space.

Comment: @parasoup: Fair enough.  I was thinking more of size difference between primary & satellite.  Of course the problem with using asteroids as examples of that is that we wouldn't be able to spot really small satellites with telescopes.  And while we've had probes orbiting a few, they're AFAIK actively maneuvering on the order of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I plugged numbers in here.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-velocity

I assumed the orbit was a circle 100 km in diameter and so the semimajor and semiminor axes were each 50 km.

[image: calcs]

1 billion or 1 x 10^9 if I counted the 0s right.  That is pretty light as celestial bodies go; I checked Phobos and Ceres and they are much heavier.

The heavier the asteroid is the faster your ship will go around and around.
The cool thing about the calculator - as you add zeros to the weight of the "star" the orbital period is instantly calculated.   At the weight of Phobos (1 x 10^15) the orbital period is 3.15 days.

Comment: how do ypu arrive at this number? how does it guarantee a stable orbit?